# C#でCで書かれたDLLを呼ぶ際の構造体の宣言について

Tags: c#

お世話になります。  
　今、Cで作成されたとあるDLLをC#から利用できるようにしたいと思っているのですが、DLLの関数を呼ぶ際の構造体の作成で困っています。  
　なお、DLLの文字コードはUnicodeです。  
　C言語のヘッダファイルで、構造体の部分を見ると、1つだけTCHARが指定されており、後はcharが指定されている状態です。  
　また、TCHARの部分のサイズは256バイト、CHARの部分のサイズは512バイトで宣言されています。  
　下記にCのヘッダファイルの抜粋を記載します。

```
#define STR_MAX_LENGTH      512
#ifdef _UNICODE
#define FILENAME_MAX_LENGTH 256
#else
#define FILENAME_MAX_LENGTH 512
#endif

typedef struct {
  TCHAR             name[FILENAME_MAX_LENGTH];
  char              error[STR_MAX_LENGTH];
} FILE_INFO;
```

このような構造体をC#で再現するにはどうしたらよいのでしょうか。  
　ちなみに、下記が現在私が作成した構造体の部分の抜粋になりますが、これだとうまく結果が入らないようです。

```
public const int FILENAME_MAX_LENGTH = 256;
public const int STR_MAX_LENGTH = 512;

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack=4)]
public struct FileInfo{
[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = FILENAME_MAX_LENGTH)]
public string Name;
[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = STR_MAX_LENGTH)]
public string Error;
```

なお、DLLの呼び出し部分ではCharSetにUnicodeを指定しております。
　上記のような場合で、構造体をうまく作成する方法はないでしょうか。  
　何かアドバイス等があれば、教えていただけると幸いです。  
　よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

１つの構造体の中でUnicode / ANSIを共存させられないようです。例えばUnicode / Ansiで型を分けるのはどうでしょうか？

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
public struct Name {
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 256)]
    public string Value;
}
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public struct Error {
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 512)]
    public string Value;
}
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct FileInfo {
    public Name Name;
    public Error Error;
}
```

もしくは一方は`string`型を諦めて配列で受け取るとか。

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
public struct FileInfo {
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 256)]
    public string Name;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 512)]
    public byte[] Error;
}
```

また`unsafe`が必要になりますが、[固定サイズバッファー](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/unsafe-code-pointers/fixed-size-buffers)も使えます。

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public unsafe struct FileInfo {
    public fixed char Name[256];
    public fixed byte Error[512];
}
```

Comment: ご提示いただいたソースをもとに、質問文を修正しました。

Comment: @user29034 `fileInfo.Name.Value` でアクセスできます。

Comment: とりあえず、型をbyteで指定するようにしたら、うまくいきました。ありがとうございました。